# Pushy menu fixed to top

Tags: html, css

On this [page](http://www.stgertrudelutheran.org/) the [Pushy Menu](https://www.christopheryee.ca/pushy/) is being used. I want it to be fixed to the top. In the css from Pushy it has the css 
    `position: fixed; and top: 0;  by default but it doesn't keep the menu to the top when you scroll down and the menu disappears when you scroll down. How can I fix this?

```
/* Menu Appearance */
.pushy {
 position: fixed;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 9999;
 background: rgb(4, 147, 189); /* wasVery dark grey #191918 */
 overflow: auto;
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 /* enables momentum scrolling in iOS overflow elements */
}
```

Comment: Back up your files first... and try this. Add `body { padding-top: 44px; }`
    `.menu-btn { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999; transition: transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.68, 0.43, 0.99); }`
    `.pushy-open-left .menu-btn { transform: translate(250px,0); }`. Remove lines 54-61 in http://www.stgertrudelutheran.org/pushy-menu/scss/pushy.scss (should start with the selector `.pushy-open-left{
    #container,
    .push{`)

Comment: I'll try it and let you know how it worked

Answer (score 1):

```
       <style>
       /* Menu Appearance */
       .pushy {
       /* position: fixed;*/
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: rgb(4, 147, 189); /* wasVery dark grey #191918 */
        overflow: auto;
        visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        /* enables momentum scrolling in iOS overflow elements */
       }
       .fix{
         position: fixed;
         }
         </style> 
    <script>
         $(window).scroll(function(){

           var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 50)
            {
                $('.pushy').addClass('fix');
            }
            else {
                $('.pushy').removeClass('fix');
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this and check

```
.menu-btn {
        width: 100px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: fixed;
    }
    h1 {
        margin-top: 90px;
    }
```